# Automatically touch all files that use a certain #define (#ifdef foo / #endif)

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, scripting, c-preprocessor

Say you have a C project with tons of files, and tons of configurations managed by using the `-D` option in GCC to define some flags.

In my particular case, I have loads of files with that kind of stuff:

```
void foo( sometype *x)
{
   do_stuff_with_x(x);

#ifdef MY_FLAG
   do_additional_stuff(x);
#endif

#ifdef OTHER_FLAG
   do_some_other_stuff(x);
#endif

}
```

Now, whenever I change one of the flags, I need to clear the project and recompile all the source code because I cannot selectively *touch* the files that use this flag.

Is it possible, using **Eclipse** under **Windows**, to do that?
Maybe an Eclipse plugins, or whatever.

For linux, I might use some mix of `grep`, `find` and `touch`, but on Windows I have no idea.

Comment: Er...am I missing the point? Surely if you change the flags, the files that use those flags are the ones you want to recompile?

Comment: I _do_ want to recompile these particular files. But as you know, *make* only recompiles the files that have changed, so I need to change all the files where the flag is used.  

I'd rather do it automatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, under people pressure, I installed MSYS and used a command like this one:

```
$ find . -name "*.c" -or -name "*.h" | xargs grep "MYFLAG" -q -l | xargs touch
```

You can actually add some other filters to `find` to tune more finely your touched files.

I didn't know `xargs`, any idea on my command line?

Comment: You should probably use find's -print0 and xargs -0 options to avoid possible bugs if there are filenames with spaces or newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already cooked up a solution for Unix with grep, find and touch, why don't you do the same on Windows? You can use msys and the unix tools that come with it.

I don't have an Eclipse installation on the machine I am at the moment, but I'm sure you can  launch a batch from Eclipse

Comment: `find . -name "*.c" | xargs grep "MYFLAG" -q -l | xargs touch` does the trick, but, well, I hoped to see smething similar in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use a mix of grep, find, and touch on Windows too?

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/